# Astrid request returning empty

Tags: api, http-post

I'm trying to use the http://Astrid.com API, specifically to get data using the method under the "Request Format" section on this page - http://astrid.com/apidoc/file.README.html

The URL I built is:
https://astrid.com/api/7/task_list?app_id=[MY APP ID]&time=1&user_id=[MY USER ID]&sig=[MY REQUEST SIGNATURE]

And it returns this:
{"list":[],"time":1363131562,"status":"success"}

Seems like it worked, but does anyone know why the "list" array might be returning empty?  I've created a bunch of tasks in my profile so it should be showing those.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to sign in first with the method user_signin. If successful you get a token.

Then you need to call the task_list method providing the token. 
You do not need to provide a user id with the task_list method. It is only used to select tasks that you share with this user.

Example for signing in:
    https://astrid.com/api/7/user_signin?provider=password&app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&secret=YOUR_ASTRID_PASSWORD&sig=SIGNATURE&time=1365715302.36&email=YOUR_EMAIL

Example for getting your tasks:
    https://astrid.com/api/7/task_list?active=true&token=THE_TOKEN&sig=SIGNATURE&app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&time=1365715304.41